# My links are not working in the header portion of my website?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Ok, I have tried everything I can think to remedy this issue...The links at just the top of my site arent working.

Links anywhere else are fine.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="header" class="header1" align="center">
</div><!--end blue header div-->

<div class="logo" align="center"> 
 <table align="center" width="800px"><tr><td width="800px" align="center">
 <img align="middle" src="images/phwm_sc_logo.png" width="170" height="212" alt="logo" />
   </td></tr></table>
  <!--must be same width as navigation "header2  div"-->
</div> 
<!--end logo div-->

<div id="header" class="header2" align="center">
<table width="800px" height="80px" style="padding-top:10px"> <!--height of table must match height of div "header 2" -->
<tr>
<td width="138"><h1><a href="index.html">[ HOME ]</a></h1></td>
<td width="149"><h1><a href="index.html">[ TEAMS ]</a></h1></td>
<td width="220"><h1></td>
<td width="137"><h1><a href="index.html">[ STAFF ]</a></h1></td>
<td width="132"><h1>[ GALLERY ]</h1></td>

</tr>
</table>
</div><!--end red navigation header div-->
```

and here is my external CSS:

```
a.ex1:link {
color:#666335;
text-decoration:none
}    /* unvisited link */
a.ex1:visited {
color:#666335;
text-decoration:none
} /* visited link */
a.ex1:hover {
color:#D85D27;
text-decoration:none
}   /* mouse over link */
a.ex1:active {
color:#D85D27;
text-decoration:none
}  /* selected link */.header1 { position:fixed; top: 0px;
width: 100%; height:50px;
background-color: rgba(0, 54, 103, 0.6); /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
}
.header2 { position:fixed; top:60px; 
width: 100%; height:80px;
background-color: rgba(210, 6, 46, 0.4); /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
}

.logo {position:fixed; top: 5px;
 z-index:10; width:100%; 
}
```

I can always include more of both the HTML and CSS if needed...Help!! How do i fix this?

Comment: The problem is the logo within the TD that's rendered over them. So when you click (or hover) a link, you're not clicking a link but rather that logo TD. your `.logo` has `z-index: 10;` which puts it above those links.

Comment: Unless you changed the links above, they are all pointing to the same page, your homepage

Comment: You are reusing the same id. An id is supposed to be unique.

Comment: I think there's plenty of answers to your question - I'd just say that you might find it useful to use the 'Inspect Element' in Google Chrome (or Firefox with the Firebug extension). I took a quick look at your site and inspected one of the links - it highlighted the big ole `td` straight away.

Comment: Consider using jsfiddle next time in order for us to be easier to see through your code :). As @RobertKoritnik your logo is hovering your links

Answer (score 0):

The table containing your center logo is overlaying the links, so when you think you're clicking on the links, you're actually clicking on the table - preventing the links from being accessed. Make the logo container the same size as the logo and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks...but now i cant get my logo centered AND float with the rest of the page. I can get it fixed and centered...

Comment: position is absolutely and use margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; and adjust the z-index accordingly. Just make sure it's parent element is position:relative; so you can position the logo from its parent's XY. As others have suggested, tables aren't really the best way to go for layout, so I'd look at removing them altogether.